# How to show reciprocal relationships from user follower related table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been trying to follow Michael Hartl's tutorial. I therefore have a database set up as shown:

[image]

I would like to only show when a user (eg userA) is following another user (eg userB) and and userB is following userA back.

I am trying to define this in the model and will then perform an ajax call from a controller action.

I tried to use the answer from another [question](http://www.widecodes.com/0mSjegVePj/how-do-i-write-this-query-in-rails-for-autocomplete-using-jquery-tokeninput.html) . This is what I have so far

user.rb

```
def reciprocal_followers
  self.followers & self.followed_users
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
def reciprocal_followers
  @reciprocal_followers =current_user.reciprocal_followers
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% @reciprocal_followers %>
```

but I get nothing in return

so I changed the index.html.erb to

```
<%= current_user.reciprocal_followers %>
```

and I get the results I expect although if I just want the id or name of the reciprocal_followers I get 'undefined' errors.

How can I get a list of reciprocal followers

Comment: Could you please clarify this part of your question "and I get the results I expect although if I just want the id or name of the reciprocal_followers I get 'undefined' errors." It seems like you're saying you're retrieving the correct set of records via the "<%= current_user.reciprocal_followers %>" query. Maybe you could post the code which generates the error you mention?

Comment: If I use <%= current_user.reciprocal_followers %> then I get the entire record for all the relevant users. The reciprocal users are correct I just want the names however, and not the entire record. If I then use <%= current_user.reciprocal_followers.name %> then I get the error 'undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x007f066e3a2980>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bouncing on your comment about `undefined method`

When you use the `&` operator, it performs an operation on arrays, meaning it loads the content of the database already. In other words

```
self.followers & self.followed_users
```

is equivalent to

```
self.followers.to_a & self.followed_users.to_a
```

And will return an array of follower objects.

You can actually do this to get their ids :

```
<%= current_user.reciprocal_followers.map(&:id) %>
```

It will return an array of the `reciprocal_follower` ids

Comment: Can you write the full error ? `.map` [is a Ruby method for Arrays](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) so if it returns undefined, it means `@reciprocal_followers` is NOT an array. Did you try using `current_user.reciprocal_followers.map(&:id)` instead of `@reciprocal_followers.map(&:id)` ?

Comment: Great that worked. So I guess @reciprocal_followers isn't an array so I'm not sure what it is. Anyway it has worked

Answer (score 0):

Please change this line in your index.html.erb

```
<% @reciprocal_followers %>
```

To this

```
<%= @reciprocal_followers %>
```

And let me know what happens

Comment: Actually neither returns anything. The only line that does is  <%= current_user.reciprocal_followers %> . Removing the = in this latter statement also does not return anything

Comment: I'm glad you got the answer from @Cyril, but keep in mind for the future, if you want to display the var referenced you need the "<%=". "<%" without the equal will not display anything, ever. Note Cyril's answer has "<%=" to display the records. Try it without the equal if you'd like proof of the concept.